# Fastest way to create a sparse matrix of the form A.T * diag(b) * A + C?

Tags: numpy, scipy, linear-algebra, sparse-matrix, hessian-matrix

I'm trying to optimize a piece of code that solves a large sparse nonlinear system using an interior point method. During the update step, this involves computing the Hessian matrix `H`, the gradient `g`, then solving for `d` in `H * d = -g` to get the new search direction.

The Hessian matrix has a symmetric tridiagonal structure of the form:

> *A.T * diag(b) * A + C*

I've run [`line_profiler`](http://pythonhosted.org/line_profiler/) on the particular function in question:

```
Line # Hits     Time  Per Hit % Time Line Contents
==================================================
   386                               def _direction(n, res, M, Hsig, scale_var, grad_lnprior, z, fac):
   387                               
   388                                   # gradient
   389   44  1241715  28220.8    3.7     g = 2 * scale_var * res - grad_lnprior + z * np.dot(M.T, 1. / n)
   390                               
   391                                   # hessian
   392   44  3103117  70525.4    9.3     N = sparse.diags(1. / n ** 2, 0, format=FMT, dtype=DTYPE)
   393   44 18814307 427597.9   56.2     H = - Hsig - z * np.dot(M.T, np.dot(N, M))    # slow!
   394                                   
   395                                   # update direction
   396   44 10329556 234762.6   30.8     d, fac = my_solver(H, -g, fac)
   397                                   
   398   44      111      2.5    0.0     return d, fac
```

Looking at the output it's clear that constructing `H` is by far the most costly step - it takes considerably longer than actually solving for the new direction.

`Hsig` and `M` are both CSC sparse matrices, `n` is a dense vector and `z` is a scalar. The solver I'm using requires `H` to be either a CSC or CSR sparse matrix.

Here's a function that produces some toy data with the same formats, dimensions and sparseness as my real matrices:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse

def make_toy_data(nt=200000, nc=10):

    d0 = np.random.randn(nc * (nt - 1))
    d1 = np.random.randn(nc * (nt - 1))
    M = sparse.diags((d0, d1), (0, nc), shape=(nc * (nt - 1), nc * nt),
                     format='csc', dtype=np.float64)

    d0 = np.random.randn(nc * nt)
    Hsig = sparse.diags(d0, 0, shape=(nc * nt, nc * nt), format='csc',
                        dtype=np.float64)

    n = np.random.randn(nc * (nt - 1))
    z = np.random.randn()

    return Hsig, M, n, z
```

And here's my original approach for constructing `H`:

```
def original(Hsig, M, n, z):
    N = sparse.diags(1. / n ** 2, 0, format='csc')
    H = - Hsig - z * np.dot(M.T, np.dot(N, M))    # slow!
    return H
```

Timing:

```
%timeit original(Hsig, M, n, z)
# 1 loops, best of 3: 483 ms per loop
```

Is there a faster way to construct this matrix?

Comment: My NumPy won't let me do `np.dot(M.T, np.dot(N, M))`. Does it definitely run on your machine? Do you want to do `N.dot(M)`?

Comment: @MrE I suspect it's probably a version issue - `numpy.dot()` is overridden for sparse matrices as of [this commit](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/2732) 8 months ago.

Comment: You don't need `dot`, just `Hsig - z * M.T * (N * M)`, but I don't know whether it's faster.

Comment: @HYRY Yeah, I know - I almost always work with ndarrays rather than matrices, so the `np.dot()` syntax feels more natural to me than `*`. There's no real performance difference, since both just call the `.__mul__()` method of the sparse matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get close to a 4x speed-up in computing the product `M.T * D * M` out of the three diagonal arrays. If `d0` and `d1` are the main and upper diagonal of `M`, and `d` is the main diagonal of `D`, then the following code creates `M.T * D * M` directly:

```
def make_tridi_bis(d0, d1, d, nc=10):
    d00 = d0*d0*d
    d11 = d1*d1*d
    d01 = d0*d1*d
    len_ = d0.size
    data = np.empty((3*len_ + nc,))
    indices = np.empty((3*len_ + nc,), dtype=np.int)
    # Fill main diagonal
    data[:2*nc:2] = d00[:nc]
    indices[:2*nc:2] = np.arange(nc)
    data[2*nc+1:-2*nc:3] = d00[nc:] + d11[:-nc]
    indices[2*nc+1:-2*nc:3] = np.arange(nc, len_)
    data[-2*nc+1::2] = d11[-nc:]
    indices[-2*nc+1::2] = np.arange(len_, len_ + nc)
    # Fill top diagonal
    data[1:2*nc:2] = d01[:nc]
    indices[1:2*nc:2] = np.arange(nc, 2*nc)
    data[2*nc+2:-2*nc:3] = d01[nc:]
    indices[2*nc+2:-2*nc:3] = np.arange(2*nc, len_+nc)
    # Fill bottom diagonal
    data[2*nc:-2*nc:3] = d01[:-nc]
    indices[2*nc:-2*nc:3] = np.arange(len_ - nc)
    data[-2*nc::2] = d01[-nc:]
    indices[-2*nc::2] = np.arange(len_ - nc ,len_)

    indptr = np.empty((len_ + nc + 1,), dtype=np.int)
    indptr[0] = 0
    indptr[1:nc+1] = 2
    indptr[nc+1:len_+1] = 3
    indptr[-nc:] = 2
    np.cumsum(indptr, out=indptr)

    return sparse.csr_matrix((data, indices, indptr), shape=(len_+nc, len_+nc))
```

If your matrix `M` were in CSR format, you can extract `d0` and `d1` as `d0 = M.data[::2]` and `d1 = M.data[1::2]`, I modified you toy data making routine to return those arrays as well, and here's what I get:

```
In [90]: np.allclose((M.T * sparse.diags(d, 0) * M).A, make_tridi_bis(d0, d1, d).A)
Out[90]: True

In [92]: %timeit make_tridi_bis(d0, d1, d)
10 loops, best of 3: 124 ms per loop

In [93]: %timeit M.T * sparse.diags(d, 0) * M
1 loops, best of 3: 501 ms per loop
```

---

The whole purpose of the above code is to take advantage of the structure of the non-zero entries. If you draw a diagram of the matrices you are multiplying together, it is relatively easy to convince yourself that the main (`d_0`) and top and bottom (`d_1`) diagonals of the resulting tridiagonal matrix are simply:

```
d_0 = np.zeros((len_ + nc,))
d_0[:len_] = d00
d_0[-len_:] += d11

d_1 = d01
```

The rest of the code in that function is simply building the tridiagonal matrix directly, as calling `sparse.diags` with the above data is several times slower.

Comment: That is impressively quick. I'm still trying to wrap my head around how it works. If I wanted to construct just the main and upper/lower diagonals of `M.T * D * M` as dense vectors, how would I obtain these?

Answer (score 0):

I tried running your test case and had problems with the `np.dot(N, M)`.  I didn't dig into it, but I think my numpy/sparse combo (both pretty new) had problems using `np.dot` on sparse arrays.

But `H = -Hsig - z*M.T.dot(N.dot(M))` runs just fine.  This uses the `sparse dot`.

I haven't run a profile, but here are Ipython timings for several parts.  It takes longer to generate the data than to do that double dot.

```
In [37]: timeit Hsig,M,n,z=make_toy_data()
1 loops, best of 3: 2 s per loop

In [38]: timeit N = sparse.diags(1. / n ** 2, 0, format='csc')
1 loops, best of 3: 377 ms per loop

In [39]: timeit H = -Hsig - z*M.T.dot(N.dot(M))
1 loops, best of 3: 1.55 s per loop
```

`H` is a

```
<2000000x2000000 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 5999980 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>
```

Comment: As I mentioned above, the issues with `np.dot(N, M)` are version-related - in recent versions of scipy, the `.dot()` method of sparse arrays overrides `np.dot()`, so in my case the two are equivalent (and for some reason the `np.dot(A, B)` syntax feels more comfortable to me :-)). Regarding the timings, I only construct `Hsig` and `M` once but the `_direction()` function is called 1000s of times, so I really do care about the overhead involved in constructing `H`.

Comment: The sparse .dot is just matrix multiplication, so you could write `M.T*(N*M)` or even `M.T*N*M`.  Not that there's any speed difference.    The sparsetools.csr.h file references this SMMP paper: http://www.mgnet.org/~douglas/Preprints/pub0034.pdf