# Right multiplication of a dense array with a sparse matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, matrix-multiplication, sparse-matrix

If I have a `numpy.ndarray` `A` and a `scipy.sparse.csc_matrix` `B`, how do I take `A` dot `B`? I can do `B` dot `A` by saying `B.dot(A)`, but the other way I can only think of this:

```
B.T.dot(A.T).T
```

Is there a more direct method to do this?

Comment: Why not simply `A.dot(B)` (or `np.dot(A, B)`)? Am I missing something here?

Comment: The dense `dot` probably can't handle a sparse matrix.  But the sparse version will know about arrays.  I wonder about the speed of this v.v `A.dot(B.A)`

Comment: @hpaulj Yes it will, although the result will of course be dense

Comment: @hpaulj Ah, I see that it may be a version issue. The `dot` override was added in [this PR](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/2869), and is not present in versions of scipy older than 0.14.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question initially confused me, since for my version of scipy, `A.dot(B)` and `np.dot(A, B)` both work fine; the `.dot` method of the sparse matrix simply overrides `np.dot`. However it seems that this feature was added in [this pull request](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/2869), and is not present in versions of scipy older than 0.14.0. I'm guessing that you have one of these older versions.

Here's some test data:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse

A = np.random.randn(1000, 2000)
B = sparse.rand(2000, 3000, format='csr')
```

**For versions of scipy >= 0.14.0**, you can simply use:

```
C = A.dot(B)
C = np.dot(A, B)
```

**For versions < 0.14.0**, both of these will raise a `ValueError`:

```
In [6]: C = A.dot(B)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-7fbaa337fd94> in <module>()
----> 1 C = A.dot(B)

ValueError: Cannot find a common data type.
```

Instead, you could use one of:

```
# your original solution
%timeit B.T.dot(A.T).T
# 10 loops, best of 3: 93.1 ms per loop

# post-multiply A by B
%timeit B.__rmul__(A)
# 10 loops, best of 3: 91.9 ms per loop
```

As you can see there's basically no performance difference, although I personally think the second version is more readable.

---

### Update:

As @shaoyl85 just pointed out, one can just use the `*` operator rather than calling the `__rmul__()` method directly:

```
# equivalent to B.__rmul__(A)
C = A * B
```

It seems that matrices have a higher priority when determining the behavior of the `*` operator than ndarrays. This is a potential gotcha for those of us who are more used to the behavior of ndarrays (where `*` means elementwise multiplication).

Comment: Turns out we visited this issue a year ago: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23144255/901925

Comment: Interesting. I was indeed using an earlier version. And on seeing your answer I realize that I can simply do `A * B` which effectively calls the `__rmul__`.

Comment: Ah, it didn't occur to me to try `*` - I'm much more used to dealing with arrays rather than matrices (where `*` means element-wise multiplication). In fact this is a potential gotcha: it's not at all obvious that it's the matrix in the expression that determines the behavior of the `*` operator, rather than the ndarray.

Comment: I think so. In this case the `__rmul__` is called simply because `A.__mul__(B)` returns `NotImplemented`. Otherwise the behavior may become an element-wise multiplication.